# Difference between OAuth 2.0 "state" and OpenID "nonce" parameter? Why state could not be reused?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

OAuth 2.0 defines "state" parameter to be sent in request by client to prevent cross-site request attacks. Same is mentioned in OpenID spec for "nonce". Apart from the fact that "nonce" is returned in ID token instead of query parameters, they appear to serve the exact same purpose. If someone can explain why they are separate

Comment: just found an incredibly good article that answers the question in deep https://danielfett.de/2020/05/16/pkce-vs-nonce-equivalent-or-not/

Answer (score 157):

State and nonce seem to be similar. But if you dig deep, you will find that they serve different purposes.

**State** is there to protect the end user from cross site request forgery(CSRF) attacks. It is introduced from OAuth 2.0 protocol [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12). Protocol states that,

> Once authorization has been obtained from the end-user, the
> authorization server redirects the end-user's user-agent back to the
> client with the required binding value contained in the **"state"**
> parameter.  The binding value enables the client to verify the
> validity of the request by matching the binding value to the
> user-agent's authenticated state

And this is used in authorization request. It enables the client to validate that the authorization response is not altered and sent by the original server which auth. request was sent. In short, it allows the client to cross check the authorization request and response.

*(More elaboration : To accept authorization code response, client need to accept a response from authorization server (ex:- In web app, this can be done by a redirect and a form post to back-end). This means, our client application have an endpoint which is open and accept requests. State parameter protect this endpoint by binding original authorization requests to responses. This is CSRF protection.)*

**Nonce** serves a different purpose. It binds the tokens with the client. It serves as a token validation parameter and is introduced from [OpenID Connect specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowSteps).

> **nonce** - String value used to associate a Client session with an ID Token, and to mitigate replay attacks. The value is passed through unmodified from the Authentication Request to the ID Token. If present in the ID Token, Clients MUST verify that the nonce Claim Value is equal to the value of the nonce parameter sent in the Authentication Request. If present in the Authentication Request, Authorization Servers MUST include a nonce Claim in the ID Token with the Claim Value being the nonce value sent in the Authentication Request. Authorization Servers SHOULD perform no other processing on nonce values used. The nonce value is a case sensitive string

As you can see, nonce value originates from the authorization request and it is generated by the client. And if nonce is included, it will be present in the token. So the client can validate the token it received against the initial authorization request, thus ensuring the validity of the token.

Also, depending on the flow type, **nonce** can be a mandatory parameter. The implicit flow and hybrid flow mandate **nonce** value. Both values are **generated** and **validated** by client application.

**Why state could not be reused?**

If an authorization request is captured, then the malicious party can fake the authorization response. This can be avoided by altering state parameter.

Comment: What would be the downside, if we pass state itself in the ID token as nonce and also outside it. Use the outside one to prevent CSRF and inside one to Bind session on client side.

Comment: @dvsakgec From protocol perspective, what matter is utilising state and nonce for security & validations. As far as I know specs doesn't restrict you from using same value for state and nonce. In a sophisticated attack vector, one may be able to extract state value from authorisation response (ex:- mobile application). So having the same values remove one condition from your token validation process, which is not good

Comment: Sorry for being late, but for argument that state parameter can be taken out from response completely kills the purpose of state parameter. Also, if same parameter is used in both then in case of OpenID Connect flow, sophisticated attack won't work as ID token collected from back channel call will have the same parameter and client can compare the state parameter from both calls to check validity of the call made earlier.

Comment: @KavinduDodanduwa Thanks for the good explanation. Nonce seems to be much more secure, so why do we need to put a state parameter in, if it will be manipulated, and we can put the nonce parameter in?

Comment: @avisiboni to accept authorization code response, client need to accept a response from authorization server (ex:- In webpage, this can be done by a redirect and a form post to back end). This means, our client application have an endpoint which is open and accept requests. State parameter protect this endpoint by binding original authorization requests to responses. This is CSRF protection. Nonce is totally different and both server different purposes.

Comment: @KavinduDodanduwa Thanks:)

Answer (score 17):

Nonce answers the question to the browser: Is this ID token a response to my initial request?

State answers to the backend server: did the consent really come from who I think it did?

So they answer similar questions but to different entities.

Comment: Isn't that the contrary? As I understand, `state` is used in the browser, and `nonce` in the server.

Comment: @RafaelEyng you migh be right. It was a long time I dwelled into this. Probably some reference would help out. Beside the naming though, their functionality is as mentioned.

Answer (score 15):

I am stating an explanation from their RFCs. The explanation is pretty straightforward.

State

> An opaque value used by the client to maintain state between the request and callback.  The authorization server includes this value when redirecting the user-agent back to the client.  The parameter SHOULD be used for preventing
> cross-site request forgery

Nonce

> The nonce parameter value needs to include per-session state and be unguessable to attackers. One method to achieve this for Web Server Clients is to store a cryptographically random value as an HttpOnly session cookie and use a cryptographic hash of the value as the nonce parameter. In that case, the nonce in the returned ID Token is compared to the hash of the session cookie to detect ID Token replay by third parties. A related method applicable to JavaScript Clients is to store the cryptographically random value in HTML5 local storage and use a cryptographic hash of this value.

Reference Link: State: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749

Nonce:https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0-17_orig.html

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Just a -1 because I think the OP was moreso asking for an explanation of the difference in how the two are meant to be used, rather than a snippet of the RFC.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer that the snippet from RFC is self explanatory.

Comment: "Self explanatory" is a very subjective thing. I've read the specs and still didn't get the difference. Don't assume the same level of understanding as you have from a person who is exactly asking a question about a subtlety.

Comment: Removed the word.

Comment: How can a concept of unique identifies in each request be tied to type of a client, in the end is it not the case where there is a variable containing unguessable value to identify each request. Why we not try to link both concepts and question it rather eating up the RFC in breakfast.

Comment: No link. No rfc  number mentioned.

Comment: @TheMaster, you also do some work, right?

Comment: @MayurDighe I do. But this answer would be great if you added links. It would greatly improve the quality of the answer, IMO.

Answer (score 8):

Actually "NONCE" is enough to validate sender and response.
But before you should open the token to read "NONCE".
beacuse of this you have to accept response
if there are millions fake respose you will accept all of those to open token and read "NONCE".
But **state** is allready opened on response header, you can easly read state and easly reject fake response.
this is two level ceheck.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to the above answers which focus on the security aspect of `state` and `nonce`, if you're implementing your own 3-legged OAuth2 workflow (client, your middleware and a Federated Identity Provider such as Facebook), your middleware might sometimes need some context. For example, when the response from the FIP reaches back to your middleware before going back to your client, you may need to know more about the details of the original request (i.e., the original request to the FIP). Because your middleware is most likely stateless, it won't be able to answer that question without any help. That's where the OAuth2 `state` variable comes in. You could store any string that represents the state you want to pass between all the OAuth2 jumps so that your middleware (as well as your client) can use some more context. In the case of your client, this is used for security reason. The `nonce` is used as part of the OIDC specification for pure security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

To demonstrate the difference, let's consider a situation where `state` exists but `nonce` doesn't and the attacker is able to intercept the authentication response (redirection from the Authorization Server or OIDC Provider to the client) and inject a malicious authorization code with the same `state` parameter. This is more likely to happen for native applications and can be mitigated by using `nonce` parameter approach.

OR the attacker can easily use the intercepted authorization code on the attacker's client application to log in to the victim's account. (This can also happen if `nonce` exists because the attacker can alter the client application to bypass `nonce` checking. This should be prevented by the authorization server or OIDC Provider by detecting multiple usages of the same authorization code or giving exact same consent in a short time)

PKCE can also be used as a sophisticated method, but all of the authorization servers or OIDC Providers may not support it.

Answer (score 1):

As a MiiT actor, Mallory intercepts the ID token somehow and relays the token to Relying Party (aka protected service, resource server). Relying Party denies the ID token because no [session cookie](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#NonceNotes) in Mallory's browser. The simplified relation between nonce and session,  *nonce = hash(session, seed_rotated_regularly)*

State is a [CSRF token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention) generated by relying party in every HTTP response. As a user, Alice clicks a phishing link accidentally and her user agent is redirected to the authentication service (aka OP, IdP). Thanks to single sign-on, Alice does not notice the HTTP 302 back and forth. Assume the phishing website is allowed in redirect_uri. Relying Party can deny the HTTP request with a valid token obtain by the phishing website because state is not presented. Nonce does not work in this case because session cookie is in Alice's user agent. State cannot prevent MiiT because Mallory can get the token, state, but not the session cookie.

Answer (score 1):

## Nonce

The `nonce` gets baked into the ID token, which is a signed JWT. This guarantees that the ID token you receive is the same ID token that you requested.

Such a mechanism may seem unnecessary at first, but remember that in most cases you're using identity providers like Google which will issue ID tokens to just about anyone for any reason. So an attacker can trick your app's legitimate user into logging into an unrelated app using their Google account, then pass *that* token off to your app which, if not using `nonce` validation, will accept the token and allow the attacker to masquerade as the legitimate user for whom the token was issued.

A less secure but still better-than-nothing way to protect against this kind of attack would be to check the `aud` (audience) claim of the ID token, which is probably how this was intended to work before OIDC nailed down the more-secure `nonce` mechanism. However, such a check is not immune to replay attacks, where the same token is presented more than once.

## State

The `state` comes back to you as a parameter in the request to your authentication callback. This guarantees that the invocation of your callback is the end result of the authentication flow that you kicked off.

Again, such a mechanism may seem unnecessary at first, but remember that anyone from anywhere on the web can invoke your callback. Even if most of the security logic lives in a backend server, an unexpected invocation of your callback can still corrupt client-side state leaving the end user unable to get things done in your app. Your app can also be turned into a confused deputy sending useless or even malicious requests to the server, which may lead to denial of service or other issues.

You might think to use the `Referer` header for this purpose, but that is fraught with peril. There are lots of ways to manipulate that header, OIDC providers don't have to document where their redirects come from, and you're going to have to do full URL parsing to extract the important parts. Whereas proper use of the `state` parameter can reduce secure operation to a simple equality check.

## Both

Both the `nonce` and `state` values should be:

1. opaque: an attacker can't glean other sensitive information from them,
2. unforgeable: an attacker can't construct a legitimate value deterministically, and
3. unguessable: an attacker can't brute-force the value in a short amount of time.

Generally, generating values with a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator that have at least 96 bits (12 bytes) of entropy should meet these demands today.

Also, these values are designed to protect against common, low-to-medium-effort attacks on the public Internet. A highly resourced attacker who can hijack your infrastructure or perform TLS man-in-the-middle attacks against your app won't be stopped by these mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of `State` vs `Nonce`. I am not sure if it is 100% accurate, so let me know if anything needs adjustment. Hopefully this helps.

`State`

- OAuth 2.0: HTTP CSRF Token only
- OIDC 1.0: HTTP CSRF Token, and session ID to lookup `Nonce` for comparing to ID Token `nonce` claim

`Nonce`

- OAuth 2.0: Not part of the specification because opaque tokens (i.e. no JWTs => no `Nonce` claims)
- OIDC 1.0: ID Token claim

## State (OAuth 2.0)

User Agent calls Authz Client twice in **OAuth 2.0 Authz Code Grant Flow**. For example:

1. Start flow:
   `http://authzclient/start`
2. Finish flow:
   `http://authzclient/finish?state=AUTHZ_CLIENT_CSRF&code=AUTHZ_SERVER_CODE`

Response 1 points to Authz Server, with **redirect_uri** and **State** to point User Agent back to Authz Client.

```
http://authzserver/authorize?redirect_uri=http://authzclient/finish?client_id=client1&state=AUTHZ_CLIENT_CSRF&response_type=code&scope=SCOPE1%20SCOPE2
```

Notice there is no **openid** scope and no **nonce** parameter. This example is OAuth 2.0 only, not OIDC 1.0.

As a CSRF Token, it doesn't matter if many Authz Server calls happened between the two Authz Client calls. **State** is still valid as a CSRF Token for the second request to the Authz Client (e.g. a Web Server).

## State (OIDC 1.0)

**State** is used as an ephemeral CSRF Token just like in OAuth 2.0. However, it seems OIDC 1.0 reuses it as a long term Authz session ID too. For example, **State** is used to validate a **Nonce** claim in an **ID Token**.

**Nonce** is not part of OAuth 2.0. The original OAuth 2.0 said to use opaque **Access Token** and **Refresh Token** (i.e. not JWTs). When **Nonce** was added, I think that is where **State** was given a second purpose.

## Nonce (OIDC 1.0)

Adding an **openid** scope and **Nonce** parameter to the previous example response makes it OIDC 1.0 now.

```
http://authzserver/authorize?redirect_uri=http://authzclient/finish?client_id=client1&state=AUTHZ_CLIENT_CSRF&response_type=code&scope=openid%20SCOPE1%20SCOPE2&nonce=CLIENT_NONCE_CLAIM
```

The Authz Client:

- receives **Authz Code** and **State** query parameters from User Agent
- verifies if **State** matches any existing (i.e. unfinished) flow
- receives **ID Token** (with **Nonce** claim) from Authz Server
- uses **State** query parameter as a session ID, to lookup **Nonce** value generated at same time as **State**
- verifies **Nonce** from the session matches the **nonce** claim in the **ID Token**

During the flow, the **State** is used to do a lookup of the original **Nonce** for validating the **ID Token**.

After the flow, the **ID Token** **nonce** claim can be used to do a reverse lookup to get the original **State**. That points to the original Authz Session, which may contain extra information not in the **ID Token**.