# Purpose of state and nonce in OpenID Connect Code flow

Tags: openid-connect

I am trying to figure out what `state` and `nonce` are good for in the OpenID Connect code flow.

From what I read so far, the main attack seems to be that an attacker could intercept the authentication response, including the authorization code.
If the attacker replayed the authentication response, however, the auth code would already be used and the OP would reject the token request. 
I saw, that the spec does not *require* the auth code to be a one time password, in that case I see how a replay would be possible. We, however, invalidate the auth code after use.

I also understand that, using CSRF, an attacker could call my clients redirect-uri, using a different auth code. I yet don't see how that code would be valid at the OP. Is the idea that the attacker could *guess* a valid auth code?

Can anybody show me an attack vector, that is solved with state and/or nonce?

Comment: In "[Analysing the Security of Google’s Implementation of OpenID Connect](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-40667-1_18)" by Wanpeng Li(B) and Chris J. Mitchell there is an example of a session swapping attack, if the client fails to send the `state` value (p. 366).

Comment: Thank you, interesting paper! It does only give an explanation for state, however. Does anybody know what nonce would be useful for? – elactic 4 hours ago

Comment: I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:
* Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core - https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OpenID Connect inherits the `state` parameter from OAuth 2.0. The `nonce` parameter comes with the OpenID Connect spec. They have two different purposes. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46844285/difference-between-oauth-2-0-state-and-openid-nonce-parameter-why-state-cou/46859861#46859861) to an SO answer which explains them.

In an **authorisation** flow, you have two steps. First you receive an auth code and then you use the auth code to obtain access tokens. When you receive a response at the redirect URL, there must be a way to verify that the response came for a request which you sent. The `state` value solves this issue by binding request and response. It is the client which should validate the response.

An authorisation code is short lived (30 to 120 seconds) and I do not believe it can be the same for many requests. Usually the code must be a one-time password.

`nonce` connects tokens to original client requests. If `nonce` is present in the authorisation code request, it must be present in the id token received from a successful OpenID Connect flow. This way, the client knows the token is generated for itself and it won't consume a token injected by some malicious party.